# SQL inner join to select order items

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for orders and a table for order items.

orders table:

```
order_id   user_id    ordered_at
   1          32      2019-02-03
   2          30      2019-02-03
```

order_items table:

```
item_id   order_id    product_id
   1          1          3
   2          1          4
   3          2          4
```

Now, I want to select order items that their user_id in the orders table equal to 32. I tried to do this with SQL inner join but I could not succeed.

I attempted this query

```
SELECT * FROM orders INNER 
JOIN order_items.order_id = orders.order_id
WHERE orders.user_id=32
```

Comment: What have you tried. Show us your attempt. This is a very basic query..

Comment: Yes, you're Right. I added my attempted query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in

```
select * from order_items
where order_id in (select order_id from orders where user_id=32 and order_id is not null )
```

you could use join as well

```
 select oi.* from 
 order_items oi join orders o on o.order_id=oi.order_id
 where  o.user_id=32
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! why no need to inner join?

Comment: @Hamed your question is perfectly solvable using simple inner join. You dont need such inefficient usage of subquery.. had you shown your attempt..you would have gotten better answers..

Comment: @Hamed you could join as well

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin not my -1 though; although it deserved a -1 before your latest edit.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thanks love the positive approach, actually sometimes quick decision move away you from simple one

Comment: I think the inner join is better for that. I'm a novice in StackOverflow question MadhurBhaiya :) thanks for the help.